# Can't Remove Google com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID From Play Store App

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, google-play, admob

I recently created a Flutter app and went through the process of adding Google AdMob to the app. I gave up on the iOS version, but I got the Android version working with ads. It was a very painful process. At first, the Play Store rejected it because of a declaration, but even after changing it, it rejected it. After a while, something clicked in to place, and the Google Play store stopped rejecting it.

This was the main thing I had to add to the Android app to allow ads

```xml
   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[INSERT ID HERE]"/>
```

Ads were a bad choice for the app, so I removed them from the app. I removed the XML above from the Android manifest. The app works well, and I tested it on my phone. I uploaded the bundle, but now I get this error in the store:

[image]

Which I don't believe is true. I cannot find any trace of this permission anywhere. I unzipped the merged app bundle. I opened the AndroidManifest.xml inside the app bundle, and I don't see the AD_ID permission there.

When I click the "Go To App Content" link, I see this:

[image]

So, I went along with what it was saying and I changed my declaration back to say that I do have an Ad ID - even though I don't. Now I see this. Essentially, I interpret Google Play is saying "You do have an Ad ID in your manifest, so tell us that in the declaration", and then, when I declare that, they change their tune and saying, "No! you don't have an Ad ID in your manifest. Change your declaration". Which one does Google Play want? I wish it would make up its mind.

[image]

Why is the Play Store saying this?

Comment: Check the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your project's folder, under `/build/app/merged_manifest/release/`.  For example if you use some Firebase components (Analytics, Chraslytics ...) the `AD_ID` permission is added by these components.

Comment: That path does not exist, but I unzipped the app bundle and did not find the AD_ID permission inside the merged AndroidManifest.xml. Also, I do not have any Firebase dependencies, so Firebase is not sneaking something in.

Comment: Sorry, it is `build/app/intermediates/merged_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml`.  Do you have the `AD_ID` here?

Comment: Thanks for this. I found the file on the path you mentioned. It definitely does not have AD_ID. But, Google Play is also telling me that my manifest does not have this. I believe that Google Play is hallucinating.

Comment: This is really strange. I hope it won't cause any problems to you.

Comment: There are many people complaining about similar problems. Ultimately, I had to say that I am using the permission even though I don't use an advertising id at all. I'm 99% convinced this is a bug in the Google Play platform.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I was able to publish the package by declaring that I have the Ad ID and ignoring the error here

[image]

But this is not a full solution as the package does not have an Ad ID. I checked the merged manifest and the permission is not there.